# ¿Existe alguna combinación de teclas para imprimir caracteres ASCII en Linux?

Tags: linux, ascii, teclado

Me ha pasado muchas veces que estando con un sistema que posee alguna **distribución de Linux** me encuentre con un teclado **"desconfigurado"** o que no posea **caracteres especiales** como la **"ñ"** por ejemplo (aquellos teclados que vienen de fabrica sin la tecla ñ). Para solucionar por "asociación" automáticamente intento <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>código ASCII</kbd> (como se hace en Windows) y me he dado cuenta que está combinación no es válida para imprimir los caracteres especiales en **Linux**.

En vista de esto, me he planteado la siguiente pregunta: ¿existe alguna combinación de teclas para imprimir caracteres ASCII en Linux?

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por mejorar mi pregunta. Como haces para colocar el texto de "alt + codigo ASCII" con ese presentación de teclado? Así la próxima se hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias fedorqui. Agradecido por mejorar mi respuesta y por la explicación de lo de las teclas! Un saludo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente **combinación de teclas** en Linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> y sueltas las teclas y debe aparecer una "u" subrayada. Entonces te vas a la siguiente imagen y buscas la combinación en filas y columnas del caracter especial que quieres teclear. Es decir, debes utilizar el código hexadecimal del caracter que quieres mostrar. Aquí la imagen con los caracteres especiales en hexadecimal:

[image: Caracteres ASCII Linux]

***Por ejemplo:*** <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>5C</kbd> (5 en fila y C en columnas) daría como resultado: "\", es decir, el carácter especial de "barra invertida" (aclarando que solo saldrá en pantalla el caracter sin las comillas dobles que coloqué en ambos lados).

***Otro ejemplo:*** <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> (f filas y 1 columnas). Es necesario destacar que es una tecla para fila y una para columnas es decir f1 se lee como "f" y luego "1" y **no como la tecla directa de "f1"** existente en nuestro teclado.

**Observación:** He probado este proceso en open office y en el terminal de Linux (concretamente en Debian). Para que se vea el resultado de la combinación de teclas <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> + <kbd>código hexadecimal</kbd> se debe presionar luego la tecla <kbd>enter</kbd>